# How to fetch all data and also the number of records in table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am writing following query to fetch all details of table `bill_details`.

```
select * from bill_details;
```

Along with data, I also want to fetch number of records in this table.

Comment: [mysqli_num_rows](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) will return number of records in your table

Comment: @RakeshShetty this is PHP function and OP is not saying that he is using PHP.

Comment: check out SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bill_details) AS cnt
FROM bill_details
```

Every row of the results will have an additional column with the row count.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("select * from bill_details"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use two queries for that, or use [`mysqli_num_rows`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) if you're using MySQLi, as suggested by Rakesh. If you're using PDO, you can use [`rowCount`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php).

```
SELECT * FROM bill_details;
```

Followed by:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bill_details;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the query below, but the first column will repeat the count information:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM bill_details) A, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bill_details) C
```